# Why is Float.MIN_VALUE in Java a positive value?

Tags: java, floating-point

What do you think Float.MIN_VALUE equals to?

The next code explains where my last 5 hours went to, trying solving a bug.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    compareToZero(Float.MIN_VALUE); // Out = true false false
    compareToZero(Float.MAX_VALUE); // Out = true false false

    System.out.println("Float minimum " + Float.MIN_VALUE); // Out = 1.4E-45
    System.out.println("Float maximum " + Float.MAX_VALUE); // Out = 3.4028235E38
}

private static void compareToZero(float value1) {
    System.out.print((value1 > 0) + " ");
    System.out.print((value1 < 0) + " ");
    System.out.print((value1 == 0) + "\n");
}
```

I didn't imagined that minimum value of float will be a positive value... Can't find any use for it.

Comment: @DavidM [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Yup, I know. But there's no question here.

Comment: Made the title into a question. I ran into this issue years ago, so I've already been bit (and learned) by it. Debuggers are awesome.

Comment: I don't really get why this question is downvoted. Excellent!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per the documentation for [Float.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MIN_VALUE):

> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type float, 2-149. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal 0x0.000002P-126f and also equal to Float.intBitsToFloat(0x1).

While the name is debatable as the "true minimum value" of a `float` is `-Float.MAX_VALUE`, I suspect `MIN_VALUE` was chosen for consistency with the other numeric types. Using the names `MIN_RANGE_VALUE` and `MAX_RANGE_VALUE` (or similar) might have made the difference more clear.

To understand why this is the "minimum value" requires understanding a little bit about how Java (or [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) floating point values work. With this insight, after reading the documentation, it is clear that `Float.MIN_VALUE` is *the minimum non-zero value representable by the mantissa and exponent components of a float*. Or, the *smallest positive* value a float can represent.

The "true minimum value" is `-Float.MAX_VALUE` because `Float.MAX_VALUE` represents the maximum value that the mantissa and exponent components of a float can represent. Since the *sign* for a float is stored as a discrete bit, this *range limit* is the same for both positive and negative numbers.

This differs from how integers work in Java (and on most CPUs): they are encoded using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). (Some computer systems used a discrete sign bit, which is called "one's complement", which then has two integer values of zero: 0 and -0!)

Happy researching!